Any reason not to cover grated openings in basement?
The weather in my area is starting to get cold, and I noticed that my floor in particular has felt like a source of the chill. I took a look around the basement, and discovered that there are several (ventilation?) openings in the upper wall, entirely open to the elements.

There are four openings like this one total, each covered with just chicken wire. Is there any reason I shouldn't cover them up?
The basement opens to the outside with typical slanted cellar doors (no access from the first floor).
Edit, answering questions:

Yes, the entrance doors are storm cellar doors, and reasonably weathertight.
Frost definitely not an issue, I live in california. I have a basement and an attic, and am trying to keep the first floor, between them, warm.
Definitely not a cistern. I think.
Pictures of the water heater:




The water heater is in the basement, but the basement is not conditioned. I'm a renter, so anything I do to these gaps will be temporary. As for "how will i get ventilation", that's kind of part of my question. If these have to be open to the air for necessary ventillation, that's certainly a reason not to cover them up.

If the water heater is gas, you only need a 4" vent to supply enough air for the unit.

what kind and thickness of thermal insulation is there above the wooden planks visible in the picture?

@user721108 those are floorboards, so I suppose 0.25" of carpeting?

Can you reach them from the inside? If so you can cut a piece of fiberglass insulation and  put it between the floor joists.

@PlatinumGoose Like, crawl up onto the concrete shown in the pic and shove some  batting around the yellow wires? Yeah, I think I can do that.

I had a similar setup and that's what I did every winter.

Depending on where you're located, I'll wager you can close off those vents in the winter time (when the relative humidity is low) to keep cold air out.  And there will probably be enough air and moisture exchange with the outside to keep the humidity level in the basement to a reasonable level, even with the vents closed.
Here's what I've done with my crawl space - similar to your basement, only with much lower (4 feet) of headroom.
I have a couple of hygrometers in the craw space that allow me to monitor temperature, relative humidity, and dew point.  With an unconditioned space - like your basement or my crawl space, you want to make sure the dew point temperature is always well below the actual temperature in the space.  If the temperature falls below the dew point, that's when moisture condenses on surfaces, which is not good.
So I keep the crawl space closed during during warm, muggy days in the summer (when the dew point may be 70 deg F or more), open the vents up in the spring and fall when the dew points are lower (say 40 or 50 deg F), and close them in the winter.  The hygrometers allow me to monitor the dew point and temperature and take appropriate action should they start to get close together.  I may even pen the vents up in the summer if the outside dew point is below that of the crawl space.
I also should add that I have a dehumidifier in the crawl space, one that's WiFi controlled, that I can turn on to lower the relative humidity should that become necessary.
So that's what I recommend you do.  Close up the vents when it's getting cold (for the reason you mentioned) and monitor the temperature and dew point.  The air in most parts of the country tends to be dry in the winter and will tend to keep the humidity in the closed up basement under control.  If that doesn't seem to work - that is, the temperature is getting close to the dew point, then it might warrant placing a dehumidifier in the basement.
With all that said, if your hot water heater is gas, then you need to provide fresh air into the basement, and so to the hot water heater.  Failure to do so could lead to dangerous carbon monoxide (the silent killer) being created because of incomplete combustion.  If your hot water heater is electric, then CO is not a concern.

Does the water heater need an open vent, or if there's a vent pipe going to it, that's good enough?

@DanielB  Is it a vent pipe going to it?  Or an exhaust pipe going away from it?  The latter would be more common.  Feel free to add one or more pictures of the water heater to the question if you need help making that distinction.

Update with pictures! Sorry for the delay.

You are not very clear in your description of the basement. Are the access doors weathertight? Is frost an issue where you live? Are you depending on the heat from the upper floors to keep this area above freezing? Is the reason you need so much ventilation is that the concrete structure is part of a cistern?
You state in the comments that you are a renter. Are you willing to invest the money to insulate the underside of the subfloor ( and, ideally, covering the joists) with an air barrier and insulation? If so, this is the way to go.
The only ventilation requirements for the hot water heater is a 4" opening. If there is no other reason this is enough and only when the tank is in use.
If your hot water heater is in this uninsulated space, also consider insulating the pipes.
